# Wrong title revision used in suggested edits history

Tags: bug, editing, review, suggested-edits

The suggested edit history (accessible [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history)) shows the wrong (not the one from the moment the edit was suggested) title upon "Edit" resolution of the suggested edit. I can see why the current title is used in the history overview, but the detailed page for every review should use the title from the moment the edit was suggested.

The following screenshot is from [this suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/408077), and the post's revision history is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1271716/revisions):
[image]

As you can see, the title used in the suggested edit history is the one I entered with my subsequent edit. This seems bugged.

Comment: Can it be that the suggested edit page always shows the current title of the question, unless the suggestion edited the title?

Comment: @Daniel That is possible. However, sometimes the title is horrendous, and "Reject and Edit" would have been the best choice. The behaviour you describe would obscure such considerations.

Comment: The behavior is expected to me; I think/thought these lists always show the *current* title. For example, the closereview is full of [on hold] decorated titles while at the time of review they were certainly not [on hold].

Comment: @quid And what if I were to suggest a title edit? If it shouldn't apply to those cases, why the ambiguity?

Comment: On reflection and in view of your comment I think I missed your point. I thought you were (mainly) talking about the list of posts (not the card). However, I think there is a balance to be found.  It seems that the entries in the lists should have a *consistent* title; it would also be quite confusing if close reviews of the same q have different titles because they were edited in the interim. I am now wondering what the exact  behavior is when title edits happen. But still I take back my remark half-way as I misundrstood you a bit.

Comment: @quid Ah, that's some useful context to your reply, thanks. I definitely agree that it is best to use the current title for the list of suggested edits.